# DataSourceInitializer is not working on Spring boot 1.2

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot.I want to add some sql while database is creating like seed data.

```
@Value("classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql")
private Resource dataScript;

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(dataScript);
    return populator;
}

props.put("hibernate.query.substitutions", "true 1, false 0");
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
```

I have perform this action.But it not working on spring boot.Can any one help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of Spring Boot database initialization capabilities. The simplest way is to place a "data.sql" file in the root of the classpath. So you just need to:

- Change your sql file name to "data.sql".
- Place it in "src/main/resources".

Spring Boot will automatically pick up the file and use it to initialize the database on startup.

You can check the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) if you need to customize the file name, location, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes `spring-boot` gets more in the way than it helps; IMHO this is especially so with web applications.

What you can do to get around this is to rename the bean that you define.

```
@Bean("springBootPleaseStopTellingMeHowYouThinkDataSourceInitializer")
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
    // build it.
}
```

Now, to turn off the built in bit that looks for `data.sql` in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.initialize=false
```

There, now boot is booted out of the way.

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer because it hints to why the `DataSourceInitializer` isn't working in the original question: because a bean with that ID already exists. A way that I like better as a solution is to rename the method, though, since that's what the bean name is generated from, instead of adding the string literal value to the `@Bean` annotation. But thanks for putting me on the right track anyway.

Comment: In my case , the project was a spring boot project , but not using any of its annotations. There were no application.properties file in the classpath , still DataSourceInitializer bean wouldn't run . Providing a custom name for the DataSourceInitializer  bean made it work. 
This answer provides insight into what is going wrong and its work around.